# How to remove [object HTMLParagraphElement] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve some data from an API, It's working well but the only issue is at the top of the list of the result it adds "[object HTMLParagraphElement]". I want to remove it but I can't. here's my code: thanks in advance.

```
fetch("https://somapi.com/api/")
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Work with JSON data here

    const entries = Object.entries(data["data"]);
    for (const key of entries) {
      result += `<div>
                   <ul class="ul-post">
                     <a href="${key[1]["slug"]}"><li>${
                       key[1]["title"]
                     }</li></a>
                   </ul>
                 </div>`;

    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Do something for an error here
  });
```

Comment: I only see `result += //something` -- what is the initial value of `result`?

Comment: I'm not good in Javascript I wrote it with the help of some articles. so I don't know what you mean. But as far as I understand your question the value of the result is the combination of html tags and the data of the API.

Comment: `result += '<div>'` is the same as saying `result = result + '<div>'`. You don't define `result` in the `.then(data => {` block, so that variable must come from somewhere else. Where is it initialised? Is the `[object HTMLParagraphElement]` already in there before you start doing something with the response?

Comment: That's all the code actually the result is not initialized, I just initialized it before the loop it and it gives "undefined" instead of the "[object HTMLParagraphElement]"

Comment: Thanks alot @rickdenhaan I just initialised the result variable before everything and it did disapear. thanks again.

Comment: `"[object HTMLParagraphElement]"` indicates that `result` was a `<p>` dom element. Maybe you used `result = document.getElementById('id')` somewhere? When you concatenate a string to an HTML element (which is what happens when you do `element += \`string\``), that element will be converted to a string, and a `<p>` element (which in JS is a `HTMLParagraphElement`) will be converted to `[object HTMLParagraphElement]`.